# loop for, with the jump parameter and limit parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I want to build a function with a for loop which has two parameters (upper limit and jump), the function compiles correctly but returns null.

```
create or replace function f_for_hop(v_limit integer, v_hop integer)
return integer IS
v_score integer;

begin
    for i IN 1..v_limit loop
       case (i+(v_hop  - 1)) mod v_hop
        when 0 then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i);
        else null;
        end case;
    end loop;
    return v_score;
end;
```

in the procedure everything works ok

```
declare
v_limit integer := &limit;
v_hop integer := &hop;
begin
    for i IN 1..v_limit loop
       case (i+(v_hop  - 1)) mod v_hop
        when 0 then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i);
        else null;
        end case;
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't assigning a value to v_score in your function so it remains NULL.
Then you RETURN v_score and it is still NULL;